# Finding the numerically listed string to the center algorthim

Tags: strings, basic-lang

The algorithm takes input for a string's length for **L**, and the number of strings altogether for **X**. The hamming distance is for input **D**. Input **Z** calculates the exact amount of all possible characters in the string besides the permutations for input **D**.

We get a set of **Z** amount of characters. We divide **Z** by **D** which is **S**. We get **B** possible permutations of characters that can be generated in a list of **X** strings. In other words, **Z** divided by **Y** groupings of the same **X** should uniquely have **B** possible permutations within the **Z** characters. (For the center numerical listed string based on hamming?)

If the algorithm is, correct (or I've misled). The center of **Z** is at the **S** string which should be the **B** permutation.

NOTE: The concept is to visualize our strings as a number line.

Here the algorithm is written in *Ancient Basic* from a TRS-80 computer.

```
0 A=1
1 INPUT "LENGTH OF STRING";L
2 INPUT "X FOR HOW MANY";X
3 INPUT "D FOR HAMMING DISTANCE";D
4 Z = X * X * 1 * L + X * D * D * D + 1
5 S = Z / D
6 B = S / D
7 Y = S / B
8 CL = D * A ≤ X ≤ B * Y
10 P=B*Y
11 PRINT "CLOSEST STRING", CL, "P=", P
12 IF S = S * D / D THEN PRINT"S = S * D / D", S * D / D
13 IF D = Z / S THEN PRINT"D = Z / S", Z / S
15 PRINT"PROOF", P, S
```

I also continue with the algorithm to find where the 2nd closest string, 3rd closest, 4th and so on.

```
16 PRINT"WOULD YOU LIKE TO FIND CUSTOM CLOSEST STRING?";R$
17 IF R$=YES$ THEN GOTO 19
18 IF R$=NO$ THEN GOTO 19
19 INPUT "ENTER # FOR CLSE STRING";RT
20 GOTO 21
21 PRINT"YOUR CLOSEST STRING"RT, S / RT
90 NQ = S / RT
91 P = RT * NQ
92 IF P = NQ THEN PRINT P, NQ, "LUCKY"
```